# Why is JS 'id' returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, variables, filter

Below is my code:

```
    var activeSlide = $('.slide').filter(':visible');
    var currentId = activeSlide.id;
    console.log(activeSlide);
    console.log(currentId);
```

My first console log is returning the HTML object:

```
    [div#slide-2.slide.current, prevObject: p.fn.init[5], context: document]
```

But my second console.log() is returning 'undefined'.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please post the HTML code for your document as well.

Comment: Add the html in question

Comment: Your first `console.log()` is dumping out a jQuery object, not the DOM element.

Comment: `id` if exists is available as `activeSlide.attr('id')` or `activeSlide[0].id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `activeSlide` variable has a jQuery object assigned to it, and that won't have an "id" property.

You can get the id with `.prop()`:

```
var currentId = activeSlide.prop("id");
```

or, if you don't want to make a function call:

```
var currentId = activeSlide[0].id;
```

However if you do that you run the risk of an exception if there's really no active slide.

Comment: didnt even noticed the jquery .yaps you will have to do `activeSlide.attr('id')`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that I could not use the JS `id` property with a jQuery object.

I solved it by using `.attr('id')` rather than `.id`.

Comment: Do not post comments as answer to your question..There is already comment area just right after your question..! Use that for commenting..!

Comment: To be fair you're allowed to answer your own question on SO, and the second sentence does answer his own question.

Comment: I posted this before the other responses in case anyone else had this issue.  I was not trying to steal anyone else's thunder.

Comment: Better use `prop` than `attr`